# How do I put document get element by id in a loop in javascript/php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

How do I put 'txthint' in a loop using javascript? Like making them have differnt id's if i have more than 1 in the page. I think it's important if Im displaying different id's in hay.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function showUser(str) {
                if (str == "") {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
                    return;
                } else {
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else {
                        // code for IE6, IE5
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                        }
                    };
                    xmlhttp.open("GET","hay.php?q="+str,true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>


    </html>

    <form>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
            <option>-None Selected-</option>

            <?php
            $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','imetrics') or die ("Cannot connect");
            $query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM question");
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row["question_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["questiontitle"]; ?></option>
                <?php
            }
            ?>

        </select>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
```

this is my php code in hay.php

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','imetrics') or die ("Cannot connect to database");
if(!$con){
    echo ('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

$id= isset($_GET["q"])?intval($_GET["q"]):"";

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM question WHERE question_id = '".$id."'");

function displayOption($i, $value, $answer_type) {
    if($value == null) {
        return;
    }

    if($answer_type == "radiobutton") {
        echo '<input type="radio" name="rinput" value="'.htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES).'">'.htmlspecialchars($value).'<br>';
    } else if($answer_type == "checkbox") {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="cinput['.$i.']" value="'.htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES).'">'.htmlspecialchars($value).'<br>';
    }
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    for($i = 1; $i<=10; ++$i) {
        displayOption($i, $row["Option_$i"], $row['answer_type']);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: ID should be unique you have multiple same ID?

Comment: Whenever I choose a data from the question 2 dropdown, the input types which im manuplating in ajax are changing on the same spot under question 1 dropdown. Check this img out http://imgur.com/a/O9Oj1 @guradio

Comment: cgeck your html mark up you are generating multiple `txtHint` ?

Comment: Yes sir I am trying to. Do you have some sort of messenger like discord,skype,facebook we can talk in? I can explain it alot better there and I promise I will rate your help. Only if it's ok with you though @guradio

Comment: no need go somewhere else we can talk here... what i want to say is dont use multiple same id use class.. when you have multiple same id only the first one is recognize the others are ignored @jola

Comment: Can you show me a sample code sir @guradio

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147804/discussion-between-guradio-and-jola).

Comment: show what you have html